# Show text if current time is between 9:00pm and 10:30pm on friday

Tags: php, date, if-statement, time, hour

I am trying to show a text in a page only on Thursday between 9pm to 10pm.

At the moment I wrote this code:

```
if((date('N') == 4 && date('G') >= 21) || (date('N') == 4 && date('G') < 22)) {
    echo "Text";
}
```

but not work.

Answer (score 2):

The or was causing the problem. So it always echo out.

```
if(date('N') == 4 and ( date('G') >= 21 and date('G') < 22)) {
    echo "Text";
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the extra parentheses since it's all _and_'s